# facebook landing page not working

Tags: facebook

My facebook landing page work's when you go to the Canvas Page
https://apps.facebook.com/texansforpropeight/ but when I click the iframe tab I named welcome on my page The landing page does not show up. I have followed all instructions and have read countless blogs and tutorials and cannot seem to find the problem. If anyone has any clues, please let me know.

These are my settings.

[facebook http:///texansforprop8.com/help.png](http:///texansforprop8.com/help.png)

Answer (score 0):

I bet the tab url needs to be a fill URL. Instead of index.php probably need http://www.texanforprop8.com/index.php or whatever it is.